# VBA. Opening file with its associated application and whose path is stored in a variable

Tags: vba

Please help with this.

I don't know why this is not working:

```
Public Sub OpenFile(ByVal ImagePath As String)    
   Dim WshShell As Object 
   Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   WshShell.Run ImagePath    
End Sub
```

I am getting this exception:
`(&H80070002)`

I am trying to open a file whose path is stored in a variable `ImagePath` which is a string.

Scenario:

- ImagePath = "C:\helloWorld.txt"

When I call this function. I want file to be open with its associate software.
In this case a text viewer.

If it is a pdf file, I want it to be opened in a pdf viewer.

*Files are associated to be opened in their respective application.*

Comment: Do you have a global variable somewhere, to which you assign `"C:\helloWorld.txt"` instead of passing that into the sub? Does the file exist at this path?

Comment: No, I want to pass the path as variable.

Comment: `&H80070002` is the error number. What is the error message that you are getting?. If I am not wrong then that error message should popup when the file is not found.

Comment: This code is integrated with another application which uses vba for scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, but if I use whitespaces in the path, I get the same error. To fix this, you path must start and end with " (ex. "C:\youPath"). Change your code to this:

```
Public Sub OpenFile(ByVal ImagePath As String)    
   Dim WshShell As Object 
   Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   WshShell.Run chr(34) & ImagePath & chr(34)    
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get that error with whitespaces.. either in the path or in the file name...

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in the comments above, that error message should popup when the file is not found.

Here is one way to test it.

```
Const ErrNo = &H80070002

Sub Sample()
    On Error Resume Next
    OpenFile "C:\ImaginaryFile.pdf"

    If Err.Number = ErrNo Then
        MsgBox "File Not Found"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Public Sub OpenFile(ByVal ImagePath As String)
   Dim WshShell As Object
   Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   WshShell.Run ImagePath
End Sub
```